# how to set a string to a new division every single time a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click a button `Add Card` a function `add()` is called. This displays a `textbox`  and a `button` which then takes a value. The `button` has a `addtext()` function which reads the value. It should then set the value to a `div` inside that same area.

I am able to set the values. But the values are appened to the same `div`.

What I want:

- read the value from `textbox`
- set the value from the `textbox` to a new div everytime.

The `div` should be below the previous one.

**HTML code:**

```
<a id="newcard" href="#" onclick="add()">
  <b style ="color: #444444">Add Card...</b>
</a>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="cardarea" class="parent2">
  <div>
  <span><b class="card1" id="cardtitle">Stuff To Try (this is a list)</b></span>
  <span>
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h card1" title="List Actions" 
      tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover"></i>
  </span>
<div>

<span id="show-ta">
  <textarea class="t" id="txtarea" style="display:none"></textarea>
<span>
<span id="newbutton">
  <button id="firstbutton" class="btn btn-success nbutton" onclick="addtext()" style="display:none">Add</button>
</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#add-card{
  margin-top:25px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
  margin-right:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height:30px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

**Jquery code:**

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('textarea'));
var wrapper = $('#cardarea');
var cards = $('#add-card');
var button = $(document.createElement('button'));

function add() {
    if ($('#txtarea').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#txtarea').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if ($('#firstbutton').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('#firstbutton').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (wrapper.find('textarea').last().val().length) {
        var x = wrapper.find('textarea').last().val();
        wrapper.addClass('text-a1');
        wrapper.addClass('nbutton');
    }
}

function addtext() {
    var a = $(document.getElementById('#add-card'));
    var value = wrapper.find('textarea').last().val();
    $('textarea').css("display", "none");
    $('button').css("display", "none");
    $('#add-card').css("display", "block");
    if (cards.find('div').last().val() != 0) {
        wrapper.append('<div id="add-card"></div>');
        cards.append(value).appendTo("#cardarea").insertAfter("#cardtitle");
    }
    alert(value);
    //$('#cardarea').text(wrapper.find('textarea').last().val());  
}
```

Comment: Where is your `wrapper`? I mean you have not defined `wrapper`.

Comment: made an edit @divy3993

Comment: where is wrapper, cards, and also there is mistake in this line $(document.getElementById('#add-card'))? please provide the correct code.

Comment: Okay great, but where is your element with `id=cardarea` in HTML structure?

Comment: it is just a div element that contains the `add-card` div

Comment: added the html code for this as well. made an edit

Comment: is this section `wrapper.append('<div id="add-card"></div>')` running?  `alert()` or `console.log()` to verify?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic gist of what I think you were trying (before your edits)

Here are the some points to keep it simple:

1. wrap the `textarea` and `button` in a single `wrapper` and show/hide this form only. And, clear the `textarea` everytime you want to add a new card
2. When submitting `textarea` - read its value, create a new `div` with it, and append to `cardarea`. After that hide the `textarea`

```js
var wrapper = $('#cardarea');

function add() {
  $('#txtarea').val('');
  $('#cardform').show();
}

function addtext() {
  var val = $('#txtarea').val();
  $('<div class="card">').html(val).appendTo(wrapper);
  $('#cardform').hide();
}
```

```css
.card {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="newcard" href="#" onclick="add()">
  <b style="color: #444444">Add Card...</b>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</a>

<div id="cardform" style="display:none">
  <textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
  <button id="firstbutton" class="btn btn-success nbutton" onclick="addtext()">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="cardarea">
  <h3>Added Cards title</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: but it works perfectly in my code! thnx! One question: how do set every div to display on the next line instead of beside eachother?

Comment: can u tell what error did u get as I don't see any?

Comment: To keep appending `div` in next lines, remove their wrapping `span` tag. Check out the diff b/w i`nline` vs `block` elements. Block elements starts from a new line (eg. `div`) while inline elements doesn't takes to a new line. Check this [http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html]